# game rounds for two teams Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am making a team deathmatch game with rounds. The rounds work with one team but as soon as I add an if statement to detect whether a player is in blue or red team, it doesn't work. "

```lua
local lobbyLocation = game.Workspace.Lobby.Position + Vector3.new(0,3,0)

local gameLocation = game.Workspace.Main.Position + Vector3.new(0,3,0)

local Players = game:GetService("Players")


local Teams = game:GetService("Teams")

local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage')

local timeEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild('TimeEvent')



local function playGame()

    local timeAmount = 20

    local timerText = 'Remaining Time: '

    while timeAmount > 0 do

        timeEvent:FireAllClients(timeAmount, timerText)

        wait(1)

        timeAmount -= 1

    end

end



local function playIntermission()

    local intermission = 10

    local timerText = 'Intermission: '

    while intermission > 0 do

        timeEvent:FireAllClients(intermission, timerText)

        wait(1)

        intermission -= 1

    end

end



local function resetPlayers()

    for _, plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do

        plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(lobbyLocation)

    end 

end



local function teleportPlayers()
    
    for _, plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

            if Players.Team == Teams["Blue Team"] then 
                print("blue team")
                plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(gameLocation)
                
            else
                print("red team")
            end

    end)
        
        
    
    end 

end



while true do

    resetPlayers()

    playIntermission()

    teleportPlayers()

    playGame()

end
```

The if statement is inside of teleportPlayers() function because we want the players to teleport to a different part of the game, depending on their team.

Comment: Your question is incomplete and unclear. Please provide more code and please let us know what code isn't running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why you're having a problem with the teleportPlayers() function is because you are using `game.Players.PlayerAdded()` which only fires when a new player joins the game (not existing players)

```lua
    for _, plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player) -- this means you are detecting a new player that joins the game

            if Players.Team == Teams["Blue Team"] then -- also this is incorrect, Players is a service that doesn't have a Team
                print("blue team")
                plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(gameLocation)
                
            else
                print("red team")
            end
        end)
    end
```

Since you are already looping through all the players, what you should do is use `plr.Team` to get the player's team

```lua
    for _, plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        if plr.Team = Teams["Blue Team"] then
            print("blue team")
            plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(gameLocation) 
        else
            print("red team")
        end
    end
```